# What is the shortest way to get log4j initialized in your main method?

Tags: java, log4j

I want everything to log to the console and don't want to have to deal with creating log4j.xml files, etc. I am prototyping some libraries and want to see their full log output.

I would like to keep it as pure as possible and not have to introduce unnecessary dependencies like Spring, etc.

Comment: @Nick.  What have you got against `log4j.xml` or the properties file equivalent?  Are you trying to make it hard for people to tailor the logging?

Comment: This specific application will be used by no one other than me and I don't foresee ever wanting to control the log level of individual loggers. It's cumbersome to maintain for no benefit (imo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ALL);
Layout layout = new PatternLayout("%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n");
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(layout));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay out of configuration files completely, you can do simple configuration in few lines like this :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("log4j.appender.CONSOLE",org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender");
props.setProperty("log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold", "TRACE");
props.setProperty("log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout,"org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
props.setProperty("log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern","%-5p %d{HH:mm:ss} %-30C{1} | %m%n);"
props.setProperty("log4j.rootLogger", "TRACE, CONSOLE");
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this does the trick.

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class Main {

    private static void initializeLogger() {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main.initializeLogger();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can inline it.  Just call BasicConfigurator.configure().

Comment: I just guarded from the future in case I want a more elaborate scheme.

Comment: Ok, but then what is the name of the static logger variable?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to drop the following code into a file `log4j.properties` at the root of the classpath (i.e. your source or resources folder):

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, A1
# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %c{2} %m%n
```

Comment: Downvoted because I specifically stated I don't want a log4j.xml (same as properties)

Comment: I beg to differ - the XML-based configuration is far more cumbersome. The properties-based one is well-understood and highly conventional, doing anything else in code would only make it more difficult for other developers to understand what you're doing.

Comment: I recommend consolidating your post with @rsp's to make a more concise and informative post.

Answer (score 0):

You can build up a Properties collection with the values needed and pass that to the `PropertyConfigurator.configure(Properties)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Over a decade later I find myself asking the exact same thing.

When using **log4j2** as the logging framework, this seems to do the trick:

```java
static {
    ConfigurationBuilder<?> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    AppenderComponentBuilder console = builder.newAppender("stdout", "Console");
    builder.add(console);

    RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(Level.ALL);
    rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("stdout"));
    builder.add(rootLogger);

    Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
}
```

using these imports

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.AppenderComponentBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilderFactory;
```

#### Important side note

The logging framework can be initialized only once.
Configuration that happens after the first initialization is silently ignored.
**If something else configures the logging framework before this code is executed, this code will have no effect.**

For this reason, if your class has a static Logger field, it should be defined below the static configuration block.

```java
static {
    // configuration here
}

// loggers should be assigned after the custom configuration
// otherwise they trigger default configuration
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
```